# json decode remove the new line

Tags: php, json, decode

Find my Json code.

```
$result  =  { 
        "text_1": 
            [
                { 
                    "text": "Name \nKarSho", 
                    "left": 0, 
                    "right": 0
                }
            ]
    }
```

I want "text" from this Json in PHP. I used following script,

```
$json = json_decode($result,true);
if($json && isset($json['text_1']))
{
    $textblock =$json['text_1'][0];
    echo $textblock['text'];
}
```

It's giving,

> Name KarSho

But I want,

> Name \nKarSho

What to do?

Comment: you need to display like  this

Name 
KarSho

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, to your surpeize, it will give you, `Name \nKarSho` as output, But when you render that in HTML (In any Browser), You will not see a new line, because more than one spaces and new lines are ignored by browsers, if you go to view source of the browser, you will see a new line there,

If you want your HTML to show the new line, use

```
echo nl2br($textblock['text']);
```

So that your new lines will be converted to `<br>` tag, and you will see that in your HTML output.

---

Edit:

If you want to see also `\n` in output (as is), You just want

```
echo json_encode($textblock['text']);
```

and to remove the quotes,

```
echo trim(json_encode($textblock['text']), '"');
```

Comment: I have specified in first line of my answer, OP is already getting what he wants.

Comment: @Muhammet you are right with Logic, But It's Enough for me.

Comment: `echo json_encode("test \n test");` will print `test \/n test`

Comment: can you tell me what you see [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fc128470f406dfadadca68aa56728394737e7f75) ?

Answer (score 2):

**`OP` doesn't want a new line, he wants to print `\n` also.**

You can escape `\n`, for example:

```
$name = "John \n Will";

echo str_replace("\n", "\\n", $name);
```

will output:

```
John \n Will
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  
header('Content-Type: text/plain'); 
$result  = '{"text_1": [{"text": "Name \nKarSho", "left": 0,"right": 0}]}';
$json = json_decode($result,true);
if($json && isset($json['text_1']))
{
    $textblock =$json['text_1'][0];
    echo $textblock['text'];
}

    ?>
```

use header function to disply next line